# qbxml add customer using webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, desktop, quickbooks

I am using web service to integrate QuickBook Desktop with ASP.NET app. I need to add customer's custom field using ASP.NET library.I have added xml file to send request method in webservice but failed to add customer.

Comment: Please post your code, and the log showing WHY it failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got solution.I have maintained the request from my web application to a table in database. Then i queried it at web service and update each request with its respective response.Appreciate the help from @ Keith Palmer Jr.